# I came across this "=?' as a parameter when doing an SQLite query in android

Tags: android, sqlite

```
public Mammalia getAnimalByWalrus(int Walrus){
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    String getQ =  "SELECT  " +
            Walrus.KEY_Wale + "," +
            Walrus.KEY_Male + "," +
            Walrus.KEY_Sale + "," +
            Walrus.KEY_La;e +
            " FROM " + Walrus.TABLE
            + " WHERE " +
            Walrus.KEY_Something + "=?";//
```

I have been unable to find anywhere online as to what this parameter means, but it seems to return the parameter int Id that was set out int he function, am I right in assuming this.

Just after a quick explanation as to what it means, as I feel other's may find this useful as I couldn't find anything about it, cheers!

Comment: **[Prepared statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "?" in SQL is a parameter/placeholder for something, see [parameterised statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement#Parameterized_statements). The equals before it is a separate symbol.